# Add service worker code completion to JetBrains WebStorm

Tags: javascript, webstorm, service-worker

I am using WebStorm.

How can I add code completion for JavaScript Service Workers?

I assume I need to add the type-script file in `settings/languages&frameworks/javascript/libraries/` however I do not see it in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for Service Worker APIs will be available in upcoming 2017.3 - see [WEB-20529](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-20529).
Please try [2017.3 EAP](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/WebStorm+EAP) - it bundles Typescript stubs for most popular JavaScript APIs:

[image]